# R histogram range error: some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x

Tags: r, histogram

I have a dataset that I'd like to plot with `hist` in R. There are a number of rows in the dataset whose values are beyond a value that I care about. Specifically, my R script is:

```
library(ggplot2)    
data = read.table("input.txt", sep=" ", strip.white=TRUE, header=TRUE)
pdf("out.pdf")
hist(data$actions,breaks=seq(0,130,by=1))
dev.off()
```

An example dataset for `input.txt` is:

```
name actions
foo 3
bar 129
baz 131
```

If I run the R script, I get an error:

> Error in hist.default(data$actions, breaks = seq(0, 130, by = 1), :
>         some 'x' not counted; maybe 'breaks' do not span range of 'x'
>       Calls: hist -> hist.default
>       Execution halted

I know why this error occurs: there is one occurrence of a value greater than 130, namely `baz` with a value of 131.

What I'd like is to create a histogram *just* for the frequencies in the specified range of 0 to 130, and for all frequencies out of that range to be silently ignored. How can I do this?

Comment: drop those observations: `with(data, hist(actions[actions >= 0 & actions < 131], breaks=seq(0,130,by=1))`. Also, hist is a base R graphic, so `library(ggplot2)` is unecessary.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! If you type this out as an answer, then I'll happily accept it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way to avoid this error is to subset the data that you feed to the base R function `hist`.

For example,

```
with(data, hist(actions[actions >= 0 & actions < 131], breaks=seq(0,130,by=1))
```

Maybe a little more flexible approach is to pre-specify the desired set of values, to make it easier to adjust if you change your mind at some point.

```
myValues <- seq_len(131)-1
with(data, hist(actions[actions %in% myValues], breaks=myValues)
```